# How could a plugin PreferenceStore be accessed from other plugins?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Would somebody kindly help me about how can I access Java Editor PreferenceStore in my plugin. One way of doing this is:

org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.getDefault().getCombinedPreferenceStore();

But it is highly discouraged as JavaPlugin is an internal class and not API. What is the good way? I am working in Eclipse 3.6 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you search for [`org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PreferenceConstants`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/PreferenceConstants.html).

Hopefully it helps.